# How to use one-sided pages formatting in classicthesis without shifting title page?

Tags: margins, double-sided, classicthesis

I'm using the `classicthesis` package with the template provided on latextemplates.com (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-typographic-thesis) to write my MSc thesis. I am required to submit my thesis to the examiners in a one-sided format. Using the one-sided format is quite easy, I simply need to put "oneside" as an option when I declare the document class (i.e. `\documentclass[oneside... )`.

When I use the default "twoside" option in the document class, the title page is centred:
[image: title page with two-sided format]

However, when I use "oneside", the title page shifts to the right (except for the timestamp at the very bottom):
[image: title page with one-sided format]

Is there a way to force the first page to be centred, use the one-sided format only from the second page or otherwise fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the title page provided in the template I was using is embedded in the addmargin environment:

`\begin{addmargin}[-1cm]{-3cm}`

(contents of the title page)

`\end{addmargin}`

Removing the addmargin environment solves the problem.